# NameError when running a function where the name of an array is a parameter of the function

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, nameerror

I am attempting to write a function which imports a specified CDF datafile, formats the image as a numpy array and does some slight refinements on the image to remove background.This works fine, however I encounter an error when I try to define the name of the array as one of my parameters in my function:

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np
def importfunction(datafile, imagelabel):
    f = Dataset(datafile)
    locationfloatfield = f.variables['FloatField']
    floatfield = locationfloatfield[:]
    img = floatfield.flatten()
    img = scipy.signal.detrend(img)
    imagelabel = np.reshape(img, (256, 256)) 
    imagelabel += abs(imagelabel.min())
    imagelabel *= (1.0/imagelabel.max())
```

I attempt to label the array as imagelabel which is specified when I call the function. However when I call this function i get this error:

```
importfunction('..../CS191mk2153-M-Xp-Topo.nc', label)

NameError: name 'label' is not defined
```

I am unsure how to fix this

Comment: You have not defined the variable `label` before you passed it to `importfunction`.

Comment: What do you mean by "label the array"?  It seems like you want to dynamically determine the name of the variable you're holding it in, but why?  Since that variable is local to the function, it only exists in the function, so it doesn't really matter what it's called.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe what you want to do is:

```
def importfunction(datafile):
    f = Dataset(datafile)
    locationfloatfield = f.variables['FloatField']
    floatfield = locationfloatfield[:]
    img = floatfield.flatten()
    img = scipy.signal.detrend(img)
    imagelabel = np.reshape(img, (256, 256)) 
    imagelabel += abs(imagelabel.min())
    imagelabel *= (1.0/imagelabel.max())
    return imagelabel
```

then call:

```
label = importfunction('..../CS191mk2153-M-Xp-Topo.nc')
```